# Android repeating alarm (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY)

Tags: android, time, alarmmanager

I am trying to implement a daily alarm.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("weekdays", weekdays);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), weekdays ? WEEKDAYS_ID : WEEKENDS_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
    time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // time a type of Calendar object which is set from TimePicker
    long timeDifference = time.getTimeInMillis() - current.getTimeInMillis();
    long triggerAt = (timeDifference > 0 ? time.getTimeInMillis() : AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY + timeDifference);
    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAt, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

It works fine if I set a time in future.
But if the time difference is negative (current time- 8:00, picked time- 7:45), the repeating alarm is set instantly and the broadcast receiver is fired!
Though I have added `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` with the `timeDifference` to set it after a day, it isn't working.

Also, The `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` value is (86400000) which is smaller than the current time in milis (1387869223432), so adding it doesn't make much difference!

What am I missing here?

Ok, this is not working.

```
long triggerAt = (timeDifference > 0 ? time.getTimeInMillis() : time.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY + timeDifference);
```

After debugging, I found that if I set earlier time, then add one day time - difference then the trigger time gets lower than the current time!

```
Alarm time: 1388073636969 (8am) current time: 1388130756977 (11:50pm)
Difference: -57120008
Alarm to be Triggered: 1388102916961
 // its alarm time (8am) + one day interval (1 day) -difference (4hr)
```

How come trigger time gets smaller than current time??

Comment: Please have you solved this

Comment: yes the bracket was misplaced in the condition, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

You should add `currentTimeInMillis` too

```
current.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY + timeDifference
```

If `timeDifference` is -15 minutes, the above statement will add-up to, 
current time + 24 hours - 15 minutes, which is what you want I presume.

`AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` : Available inexact recurrence interval recognized by `setInexactRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent)` when running on Android prior to API 19.